# Should I use and add on to the existing denormalized DB structure, or create my own?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, database-design

We have a 3rd party software, and I have been asked to create an extension for it. The extension will deal with data that exists in the current software, and include some additional data.

The existing data is extremely denormalized. Most of the data I will be working with, which is for about 4-5 different entities, exists in a single table. I will need to add additional fields to most of these entities.

I see 2 ways of doing this:

1. Create a new table for the new fields, that matches the existing table 1:1 and uses the same denormalized style they use

   Pros: It would fit in with the existing denormalized database structure, and be easy to create

   Cons: Very denormalized, and I'm a bit obsessed about normalizing my databases. The current table already has over 50 columns, and it should really be split up into 4-5 different tables.

   I also don't think I can use EF easily with the current database structure (my preferred way of working with the database) and would have to manually create data models in the code instead of using EF to generate them
2. Create a whole new set of tables and use triggers to synchronize the data between the tables

   Pros: Can create the tables the way I want, and can use EF to handle database operations, and to generate the data models for me

   Cons: Need to use Triggers to synchronize data with existing table

Which do you think is the better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how much of an extension you're looking at.  If you are adding a couple of bells and whistles to the existing interface, and especially if you aren't going to have to wrap the existing interface, then you might be better off to hold your nose and live with the ugly base data structure.

It all comes down to which is a smaller pile of code to build and maintain:

1. Extension code that is made ugly by the denormalized base + extended attributes - or -
2. Clean extension code + all of the ugly table synchronization trigger code.

It seems to me that if the extension is really substantial, then 2 could turn out to be smaller than 1.  However, if you're looking at just those few bells and whistles, then 1 is probably going to be a lot smaller than 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is how to best utilize your time combined with how much control you have over the tables for now and in the future.  Personally I would create an alternate table with some relationship.  If you choose to modify the existing table you not only now have to regression test the app and test your new app but you stand the risk of future updates breaking both apps.  So I say, work with what you can control.  You're time will be more effectively used and you position yourself with less risk down the road.  Smart for you and smart for business.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I should probably rephrase the first option... I wouldn't actually edit the existing table, but create a new table that links to it 1:1 for additional data, using their same database style. It's what we've done in the past for other tables of theirs.

Comment: I would follow option one.  I think option two is way overkill and could be a management nightmare.  Consider how easy or difficult it would transfer to another developer without your assistance.  I suppose I take the position of less work, less data management and ease of maintenance combined with reliability.

Comment: I strongly agree with Jeff's position in the comment above. "Obsession" for a favorite pattern or style is not enough for a business decision. I can understand it though and have tried to change existing stuff or extend it in my own style (against what was there). It was almost always a mistake in terms of the time and money it consumed. Unless your extension is huge and you've plenty of time (which would allow you to build your own foundation in the DB) I'd fight against an obsession and prefer the easy mode. Follow your preferences in projects where you can start from scratch.